# How should I modify Lucene in order to search differently?

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am no expert in `Lucene` but I wanted to modify it in order to fulfill the requirement as:

I treat each sentence as a different document and index it in order to test the search.

For example,

**Input sentences:** Sam eats apples. Jeff eats oranges. Sam sam and sam eats apples and only apples. Jeff jeff and only jeff eats oranges oranges and only oranges.

**Current Search**

When I search for "*Sam eats apples*", current Lucene search scores "*Sam sam and sam eats apples and only apples.*" the highest because it contains the terms like "*sam*", "*eats*" and "*apples*" more and the document appears at the top.

**Modified Search**(what I want)

Now, when I search for "*Sam eats apples*", I want the document "*Sam eats apples*" to score highest because it has got the exact match (along with the sequence i.e. Sam (first), eats (second) and apples (third) according to the query).

**What I have thought to do:** Make my custom query, weight and scoring (by extending *Query*, *Weight* and *Scoring* classes).

Is it feasible? and worth? OR are there any options except this?

Any suggestion would be valuable to me since I am just a beginner in `Lucene`.

Comment: That's the toughest route, `Weight` is the place where many optimizations happen. Just try to have a look at one of the standard implementations, I promise you a dizzy spell.

Comment: I also believe that the existing library already has enough to support your type of query.

Comment: Have you checked out `PhraseQuery`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527868/exact-phrase-search-using-lucene

Comment: Not yet. I think I need to look at it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I tried `PhraseQuery` as you suggested. It did match the exact query but I needed the exact match at the top while others at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you are combining `PhraseQuery` as suggested by @MarkoTopolnik with other queries, then set slop to **0** (which is set by default) for that query which will make sure that documents containing provided search words and their sequence will be included in result and `setBoost` for that `PhraseQuery` greater than 1.0 which will increase score for result obtained by that `PhraseQuery`. I don't know if this is optimum solution for your need but it worked for me in similar situation. I had to provide boost more than 4.0 later I discovered that there was scope for improvement in my query combination. After optimising my `BooleanQuery` which I used to combine multiple queries I was able to adjusted boot values between 1.0 to 2.0